# How much exercise should a puppy get?

Tags: dogs, training, exercise, puppy

I was wondering how much exercise a puppy should get. I need to know how long the walking time should be, the playing time should be, the outdoor exercise time should be, and how long the training sessions should be. My puppy is 3 months old and it's a Golden Retriever.

Comment: For the walks you can have a look here: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7788/how-long-distance-should-i-exercise-my-husky-puppy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your puppy needs plenty of exercise. If you live in the city, take your puppy for walks daily or take him/her to the dog park. If you live in the country, make sure your fencing is good and let your pup have fun. Remember. Puppies are like 2 year olds. Don't take your eyes off them. A 10-30 minute walk is great for your puppy. Puppies will play all day. The more you play the more you will bond. 30 minutes of play time at the least is ideal. Outdoor exercise is a must. 30 minutes to and hour at the least would be great.

Puppies have short attention spans. They easily become distracted. No more than 5 minutes a day would be excellent for your pup. At the age of 1 year, 5-10 minute training sessions are ideal. I'm a mammal trainer and all training sessions should be at least 5-10 minutes long no matter what animal. Animals can get overwhelmed and/or bored if training is too long. As a general rule of thumb in the animal training world, we have a little saying that goes like this less than 5 brings trouble more than 10 makes double. Basically this means less than 5 the animal doesn't learn enough. More than 10 and the animal doesn't listen causing both of you to lose interest. So yeah, less than 5 one animal (the animal that's getting trained doesn't learn, hence the trouble). And more than 10 makes double. (When the animal loses interest you lose interest hence the double.) It makes more sense if you do it yourself and get more experienced.

It's very important for training sessions to be positive. If the animal isn't listening take a break and try again later. Always end on a positive note. If the animal does what you want, reward it and end the training session. If a training session does go bad, punish the pup. Now punish can mean many things; do not physically punish the dog. Instead figure out what it really loves. If you usually go play after a training session, postpone the playing for a while as a punishment. Ignore the pup completely. Once you feel confident that the punishment worked, go do play time. I hope this helps.