# Guidance Needed to Prevent Corgi Puppies from Barking At night while outside

Tags: dogs, training, vocalizations, junior-pets

We have twin boy Corgi puppies born in February this year.  We have tried sleeping them outside but they bark incessantly - at cars passing by our house, at cats in our yard or adjoining yards, at neighbor's dogs.  Given the hot summer, I've been sleeping them inside our house in the laundry room.  They are chewing the doorjambs now.

How do I handle the barking at night?  Am thinking they could sleep in their crate with a towel covering it on the back patio?  Any other suggestions?

Comment: what do you do with them over the day? I would assume that tired puppies would sleep at night. How is the place shaped, where they sleep? Have they something to hide inside? Maybe they feel not save and bark scary things away...

Comment: Please give more detail. If you will not response, this question may be closed...

Comment: We crated the dogs separately, with crate covers on each. They still bark at times triggered by vehicles passing, cats, dogs in other yards etc.

Comment: So the dogs are crated the whole day?

Comment: Maybe interesting for you: [How much exercise should a puppy get](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/29149/how-much-exercise-should-a-puppy-get)

Comment: We crate the dogs only at bedtime and they are free to run throughout the day.

Comment: As I see it, there are two reasons for the barking: first, they have got not enough exercise at the day (this means not only the muscles, but also the brain, you need to train with them, play games like hide and seek, they should need to think each day). Also only running freely is not what you want for them. They will not use all their power, because nature let them have a backup all time (i.e. for hunting) and if you don't find tasks for them, they will find them on their own (i.e. doorjambs, imaginary enemies like cars passing by) Please have a look in the link above!!

Comment: The second reason I could imagine would be that they are not comfortable at the place they sleep. This would mean, you need to make them comfortable with the crate (there are a lots of questions about crates and crate training here) and minimize the sounds around or let them become known to the dogs. If they would be really tired, this would be more easy, because they would think twice when deciding "barking or sleeping?". Conclusion for me would be: do not change the place to sleep each few days, but let the dogs time to get comfortable with one place.